# Concatenating two variables in Django that are being rendered via a template

Tags: python, html, django

> Semi-brief overview...
>
> --- Indices is a Python list of indices that correspond to the total number of rows the HTML table will have. For example if the column has 5 rows the list would be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].
>
> --- RowNames is a Python list of the individual names of the HTML table rows. For example [Title, Year, Author, Date, State]
>
> --- ColData is the data that will fill the HTML's tables columns corresponding to the rows. For example ["Great Scott", 1989, "James Bixby", "12-4-2011", "MA"]
>
> Here is what I need to do...

```
{% for Index in Indices %} 
       <tr>
             <td width='11%' align='right'><strong>{{ RowNames.Index }}</strong></td>   
             <td width='89%' align='left'>{{ ColData.Index }}</td>      
      </tr>             
{% endfor %}
```

> However, Django does not interpret {{ RowNames.Index }} or {{ ColData.Index }} as the ith element of the list. How can I re-code what I have above so it is interpreted as the ith element of the list?
>
> Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the index of the element via `forloop.counter0` (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#for)).

Ok, I remembered wrong. Basically you should approach the problem like this:
either create list of objects or a list of tuples. Django does not support this for reason - the programming should not be done in the templates.

Using python's `zip()` function you can create a list of tuples with the following form: [(rowname, coldata), (rowname, coldata)...]

```
mydata = zip(rowname_list, coldata_list)
```

Now in your template you can iterate over each rowname and coldata like this:

```
{% for rowname,coldata in mydata %}
<tr>
    <td width='11%' align='right'><strong>{{ rowname }}</strong></td>   
    <td width='89%' align='left'>{{ coldata }}</td>      
</tr>  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure that that solves the problem. That gives a count of the current iteration of the loop but it does not solve the problem of being able to concatenate that count onto any list in order to access a specific index of a list. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Awesome, this is how I started going about it right after I posted the question. This is the correct way to go about it. Thank you for your help.